# Know when entering and leaving car - IOS/ReactNative - Background task -

Tags: ios, bluetooth, background

He We are doing an app that helps people people paying for there parking.
We need to know when they enter or leave the car.

Our Idea was : When you enter the car you connects to the bluetooth in the car and when you leave you disconnect - Is it possibly to get an event when the connect and disconnect happens  - Even if app is not in front ?
Any one that has done this before?

Answer (score -1):

This could be possible on cars that supports BLE together with iOS' Native [Core Bluetooth Background Execution Modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1). You'll be able to listen to connect and disconnect events even on background.
**Note that enabling the background modes require App Review Approval before it get to the AppStore.**

Comment: Don't know if we can use BLE but thanx - will see if this is possibly -